# How can i get the source of the image in one div to another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on UI designing,  how can i get the source of the image in one div to another div if i click it.
Like in FB , how can i get the source of the image in fullscreen to the rightarrrow button.
 I'm using jQuery, html , css.

**Fullscreen:**

```
$('.fullscreen').bind('click', function(event) {
    var sectionId = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id');
    var outputId  sectionId.replace('ul','img');
    var fullObj = $('#singleTemp').clone();
    var imgTarget = $('#' + outputId).attr('src');

    fullObj.find('#full').attr('src', imgTarget);

    $('#fullscreenTemp').html(fullObj.html());

    var target = document.getElementById('fullscreenTemp');
    $('#fullscreenTemp').show();

    screenfull.request(target);
});
```

screenfull.js is my plugin to fullscreen

**html to the arrows:**

```
<div id="singleTemp" style="display:none">
    <div id="fullDiv" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="fs-main"> 
            <div class="fs-pic">
                <img id="full" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" alt="imagecontainer image" src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-leftarrow">
                <img  id="1" src="jqe13/image/leftarrow.PNG"/>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-rightarrow">
                <img src="jqe13/image/rightarrow.PNG"/>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-remove">
                <img src="jqe13/image/removee.png" height="20"onclick=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-like">
                <img src="jqe13/image/like.PNG" height="45"/>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-unlike">
                <img src="jqe13/image/unlike.PNG" height="45"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**html to the image :**

```
<div id="outputTemp" style="display:none">
<div id="rightoutputimgae">
<div id="rightimgId" class="rightimg"  rel="tooltip" content="
     <img src='jqe13/image/1.jpg' class='tooltip-image'/> ">
<div id="outputimageId" class="outputimage">
  <img src="jqe13/image/1.jpg" alt="Right Bottom Image"></div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li id="outfullscreen"><a href="#">
    <img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" alt="Full Screen" class="fullscreen" 
     title="Full Screen"></a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I have the image in outputimageId.

Comment: you want to open image like in fb with navigation options ?

Comment: use slider... nivoslider ,carousel... \

Comment: please be clear what actually you want to do.

Comment: Post the sample code.. what u had tried??

Comment: please explain the scenario or paste your code that can help to solve your problem..

Comment: I have the same functionality as in FB fullscreen..i have images in fullscreen which should i navigate if i click rightarrow it should move to the right next..and go to left image if i click left arrow button

Comment: use slider...fancybox,lightbox... google it..

Comment: http://css-plus.com/2010/09/create-your-own-jquery-image-slider/
here a good tutorial on slider. Read it and try to implement it.

Comment: @Karthik.k i have a idea of how to do it..i'm trying it

Comment: @anuRadha I had posted one demo below. look at that one and i m ready to clarify if any doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like following code :

```
/// First div
<div id="first">
    <img alt="example" src="\images\test.jpg" />
 </div>

// second div 
<div id="first">
    <img alt="example2" src="\images\blank.jpg" />
 </div>



var divsrc1 = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');

var divsrc2 = $('img[alt="example2"]').attr('src');
divsrc2 = divsrc1;
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc2);
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/H6vBx/)

use below code :

```
var divsrc1 = $('#first img').attr('src');
//alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc1);
var divsrc2 = $('#sec img').attr('src');
//alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc2);
divsrc2 = divsrc1;
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc2);
```

Comment: i dont have images predefined..they are dynamically generated :-/

Comment: Then use div id instead of img[alt="example"] in my code.. Get souce of image according to div id and replace it with your another image src.

Comment: var divsrc1 = $('#first img').attr('src');
//alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc1);
var divsrc2 = $('#sec img').attr('src');
//alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc2);
divsrc2 = divsrc1;
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + divsrc2);

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = $("#someImg").attr("src");

var src = $("#otherImg").attr("src",src);
```

Just set the src

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for slider effect.There are plenty of jquery slider plugins available for free.

For Example :http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

[Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-4)

Comment: yep..am looking at it..am still confused on how should i do it

Comment: Which plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("#rightoutputimgae").prop("src");
$("#otherImg").prop("src",input );
```